# Is this mysql correctly translated to sql server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this, for mysql

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(249) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `verified` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `registered` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_login` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I'm attempting to convert to sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) UNIQUE,
password varchar(255)  NOT NULL ,
username varchar(100)  DEFAULT NULL,
verified tinyint  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
registered int  NOT NULL,
last_login int  DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

That worked, but I had to omit some things, mostly the `Collate` and `character set`.  Can you tell me if I missed anything too important and how to translate those things from mysql to sql server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- `PRIMARY KEY` means `NOT NULL`.
- Constants should be in the same type as their variable.
- For generalized character sets, use `NVARCHAR()`.
- `DEFAULT NULL` is redundant (you *can* keep it if you like).

Hence:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    email nvarchar(255) UNIQUE,
    password nvarchar(255)  NOT NULL ,
    username nvarchar(100),
    verified tinyint  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    registered int  NOT NULL,
    last_login int 
);
```

Comment: Also: passwords stored as `varchar(255)` or `nvarchar(255)` are **highly** suspect. Done properly, passwords are _fixed-sized binary values_, because you only store the cryptographic hash in the DB. Even if you base64 encode the data, you'd still use `char` instead of `varchar`, `nvarchar`, or even `nchar` because the size and character set are known.

Comment: The php auth library https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth from whence this came mentioned that passwords shouldnt be a fixed or max size, unless that size was over 100 characters.  (not quite sure youre both talking about the same thing) But, your point is taken (if only vaguely understood)

Comment: @DougCassidy The new NIST password guidelines allow you to set 64 characters as the max password length. But's that's kinda irrelevant. Passwords themselves should not be fixed size; how you store them definitely _is_ a fixed size, because you don't store them in plain text. You use a cryptographic hashing function on the original, which produces the same size output no matter what you use for input.